# select from two tables mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a page which content a list of projects and I have two tables on the database table one content the info of the project and table two content the images of each project the `image_id` is the foreign key on table two 
now what I need to do is select all the info and take one image by `image_id`from table two to make it the main project image.

### this is my code

```
<?php
    $getPro="SELECT * FROM project_info, projects_images WHERE(projects_images.image_id=project_info.id)";
    $QgetPro=$db->query($getPro)or die($db->error);
?>

<div class="body2">
  <div class="main">
    <section id="content2">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <article class="col1_fx">
          <div class="pad2">
            <h2 class="pad_bot1 pad_top1">Projects</h2>
            <div class="wrapper">
              <div style="float:left">
                <?php
              while($p=$QgetPro->fetch_object()){
              ?>
                <div class="main_pro_holder">
                  <div class="pro_imageHolder"><a href="projects_details.html"><img src="images/<?php echo $p->image_1; ?>" class="imageBorder" width="260" height="150"  alt=""/></a></div>
                  <div class="pro_label"><strong class="color1"><a href="projects_details.html"><?php echo $p->pro_title; ?></a></strong></div>
                  <div class="pro_sammry">
                    <table border="0" width="260">
                      <tr>
                        <td><strong class="color_001">Bilder</strong></td>
                        <td>El Arabia</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><strong class="color_001">Region</strong></td>
                        <td><?php echo $p->pro_address ?></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><strong class="color_001">Tracts</strong></td>
                        <td><?php echo $p->pro_area_from ?> to <?php echo $p->pro_area_to ?></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><strong class="color_001">Plans</strong></td>
                        <td><a href="#">See Plans</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="right"><a href="index.php?pid=2&proid=2&prodeid=<?php echo $p->id; ?>" class="button" style="margin-top:5px;">Details</a></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- / content -->
```

what is the correct MySQLi syntax for this to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$getPro="SELECT project_info.*, projects_images.* FROM project_info INNER JOIN projects_images ON projects_images.image_id=project_info.id";
```

EDIT:

you need to use **GROUP BY**

```
$getPro="SELECT project_info.*, projects_images.* FROM project_info INNER JOIN projects_images ON projects_images.image_id=project_info.id GROUP BY projects_images.image_id";
```

Comment: this will display all the images from table projects_images with the `image_id` I need to get the info and only one image to put as the project main image

Comment: @YousefAltaf well on the basis of what ? any specific value ?

Comment: you want just one record ? or want to put some condition ?

Comment: I have say 10 projects every project has it's own `id` on table.project_info and has say 5 images on table.Projects_images an these images has an `image_id` which is the same id from table.project_info what I want is to display the info of the project and on the top display one image for that projects from table.projects_images

Comment: @YousefAltaf check the edit, I guess you want that

Comment: so with the `while($p=$QgetPro->fetch_object())` I get the image info by `id` and the first image of the project listed on the second table.projects_images

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42328/discussion-between-yousef-altaf-and-deepanshu)

Comment: @YousefAltaf sorry didnt get you !! do you want like 10 projects then you want 10 records in your result with each project havin their image once ?

Comment: @YousefAltaf please check the new edit

Answer (score 0):

Use join Query,

```
 select * from project_info a join projects_images b on b.image_id = a.image_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$getPro = "SELECT DISTINCT project_info.*,
            projects_images.imageName
FROM project_info
JOIN projects_images on(projects_images.image_id=project_info.id)
```

Please try this one. I think this will resolve your issue.

Here distinct will return one combination at once.

Secondly you may use GROUPBY clause

```
$getPro = "SELECT project_info.*,
       projects_images.*
FROM project_info
JOIN projects_images on(projects_images.image_id=project_info.id)
GROUP BY project_info.id";
```

Answer (score 0):

the MySQL that worked with me was this

```
$getPro="SELECT DISTINCT project_info.*, projects_images.image_id,image FROM project_info INNER JOIN projects_images ON projects_images.image_id=project_info.id GROUP BY projects_images.image_id";
```

I just added `projects_images.image_id,image` to get the image id from info table and the image from images table.
Thanks for all